# Alternative to a factory(class design)

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'm writing a Synthesizer with a pipe and stage architecture. I currently create my stages in this way :

**main.cpp**

```
Stage *s1 = pipeLine.AddStage(StageRegistry::StageId::SIN_OSCILLATOR);
Stage *s2 = pipeLine.AddStage(StageRegistry::StageId::WAVE16BIT_WRITER);
Stage *s3 = pipeLine.AddStage(StageRegistry::StageId::LINEAR_ENVELOPE);
Stage *s4 = pipeLine.AddStage(StageRegistry::StageId::MULTIPLIER);
```

I'm using a Factory method in a class called StageRegistry. It became pretty clear that every specialized stage class has variable parameters and that this won't work out for me. I'm currently hard-coding all the constructor params :

**StageRegistry.cpp**

```
Stage* StageRegistry::CreateStage(const StageId stageId)
{
    Stage *s = nullptr;

    switch (stageId)
    {
        case StageId::SIN_OSCILLATOR:
        {
            return new SinOscillator(48);
        }
        break;

        case StageId::WAVE16BIT_WRITER:
        {
            return new WaveFileWriter("out1.wav", 1);
        }
        break;

        case StageId::LINEAR_ENVELOPE:
        {
             return new LinearEnvelope(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.8f);
        }

        case StageId::MULTIPLIER:
        {
            return new Multiplier();
        }
        break;
    }

    return s;
}
```

What are my alternatives? It's important that I return a Generic Stage* class to avoid casting to specific classes for pipe connections.

**main.cpp**

```
SharedBuffer *sb0 = pipeLine.CreatePipe();
SharedBuffer *sb1 = pipeLine.CreatePipe();
SharedBuffer *sb2 = pipeLine.CreatePipe();
s1->SetOutputPipe(0, sb0);
s3->SetOutputPipe(0, sb1);
s4->SetInputPipe(0, sb0);
s4->SetInputPipe(1, sb1);
s4->SetOutputPipe(0, sb2);
s2->SetInputPipe(0, sb2);
```

I'm really early in my architecture so I would like to nail this down properly, some literature and general advice is what I would like. I'm not sure what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possibility would be letting classes register itself at the StageRegistry. The StageRegistry would look like this:

```
typedef Stage* (*CreateStage)();
typedef map<StageId, CreateStage> CreateStageMap;
CreateStageMap CreateStageFunctions;

StageRegistry::RegisterStage(const StageId stageId, CreateStage CreateStageFunction)
{
    CreateStageFunctions[stageId]=CreateStageFunction;
}

Stage* StageRegistry::CreateStage(const StageId stageId)
{
    if (CreateStageFunctions.find(stageId) == CreateStageFunctions.end() )
        return nullptr;

    CreateStage CreateStageFunc =CreateStageFunctions[stageId];
    Stage *s = *CreateStageFunc();
    return s;
}
```

For a class to register itself, define a function which creates itself;

```
Stage* CreateLinearEnvelope()
{
     return new LinearEnvelope(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.8f);
}
```

And register at the registry during startup of your program;

```
RegisterStage(tageId::LINEAR_ENVELOPE, &CreateLinearEnvelope);
```

The factory function could possibly also be a class member;

```
typedef Stage* (Stage::*CreateStage)();
```

`RegisterStage` and `CreateStageFunctions` can probably be static if the initialisation is single-threaded or you take care of synchronization.